# How to put data into HTML elements in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am really new to JSP and I am trying to figure out how to show my data from an ArrayList in my HTML?

Could I do something like this:

```
<article>
 <p><%= myArrayList.elementAt(0).toString() %></p>
</article>
```

Or do I use an out.printnln?

Any guidance is much appreciated. And the question really applies to more than just an ArrayList, it is more of that I have String data retrieved my java classes, and I need to display it in my HTML.

As always, thanks!

Comment: don't use scriptlets, use jstl http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Yes it should work that way. Yet you only show the first element, you need to put that inside a loop to show everything

```
  <% for(Object obj : myArrayList) { %>
  <article>
     <p><%= obj.toString() %></p>
  </article>
  <% } %>
```

2 `out.println` is the same than `<%=`. Better use the latter to show clearly the HTML code, `out.println` would be for complicated expressions (to avoid opening and closing `<%=` too often for readability.

Comment: Hey thanks, that clears a lot up. I know scriptlets are a pain, but my first project of my internship requires them :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${myArrayList}" var="product" varStatus="loop">
            <td>
                 ${product.id}
                 ${product.name}
            </td>
</c:forEach>
```

will call the getName(), and getId() methods and output them to html.